# Ncalc, set parameters

Tags: c#, ncalc

i recently approached to NCalc library to execute some expressions retrieved from a db.
So, i created a method that process expression's formula and after, bind the values for the parameters.
At a first look, i believed that when i build an expression using the sintax

```
Expression ex = new Expression([formula-from-db], Evaluateoptions);
```

The library creates the expression, the expression tree and populates the Parameters Dictionary with parameter's names, so i can read them to evaluate.
But after playing with expressions i figured out that parameters dictionary need to be manually-populated.
This makes parameters verification a bit annoying.
It's correct or there's a method to get parameters from formula at Expression creation time?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've removed the ASP.NET Core tag here as it doesn't seem relevant to your question. Please only add relevant tags to your question.

Comment: I parse the formula with regex to get all the parameters. But I saw this answer that might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013542/get-the-parameters-in-an-expression-using-ncalc