# Find Parameters in NCalc Expression

Tags: c#, ncalc

In principle my question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013542/get-the-parameters-in-an-expression-using-ncalc), but in my case the variables are not simply X or Y, but pretty complex. My expression looks like

```
"plc3.gs_Data[1].tag1 + plc3.gs_Data[1].tag2"
```

and I would like to get a List {"plc3.gs_Data[1].tag1", "plc3.gs_Data[1].tag2"} as result, but NCalc.Compile() throws an Exception "missing EndOfFile at line 1:6" (which is the first character after the first period). Adding quotes around the parameters doesn't help.

Comment: Do you mean that you are referring to the plc object 3 and its gs_Data property, which is actually an array, its element at index 1 and the tag1 property?

Comment: yes. The NCalc parser tries to do too much here, it would be (in this case) better if it simply passed everything it doesn't understand as a symbol to my code. But that's not the way NCalc works, and I understand why, and meanwhile I found a workaround. I defined a new function symbol() which takes a string parameter, so now my expression is symbol("plc3.gs_Data[2].tag1") + symbol("plc3.gs_Data[1].tag2"), and all is well

Comment: You can try using NFun instead of NCalc - it works fine with complex input models and should be well suited for your task.

Answer (score 0):

NCalc does not work with complex input/output modules. If you need Ncalc functionality but with complex models - use [NFun](https://github.com/tmteam/NFun) instead of Ncalc:

```
double result = Funny.Calc<MyComplexInputModel, double> (
                   "plc3.gs_Data[1].tag1 + plc3.gs_Data[1].tag2", 
                    complexInputModel)
```